# Mongodb ensure the correctness of array and count in single query

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

> {   id = "castle",
>   tags = [ "Red", "Black", "White"
>            ], 
>   count:3 }

I have a collection like above, a tags array with a unique item and counter of array.

I would like to add a tags and increment the tags count in a single query.

> var query = Query.EQ("id", "castle");
>   var update = Update.AddToSetWrapped("tags", "White").Inc(count", 1);
>   Photo.Update(query, update);

What I expected is that the first part of this query is invalid because "White" is already in tags array so $inc will not execute.

But the actual result is tag doesn't insert(correct) and the counter get increment(surprise!).

I would like to know if I can do it in single query in above case.

I am using mongodb offical C# driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a limitation of MongoDB. There is no "trigger" or "update x if `addToSet` works".

There is an outstanding bug in the MongoDB JIRA system [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-786). There's a similar bug [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2769). If you want this fixed you'll have to Vote on them. Of course, that first one has been open for over a year and is not scheduled, so it's not currently deemed that important.

Answer (score 0):

Given MongoDB limitations, you can query records with id="castle" that don't have a "White" tag. Then run the update only if you get any records.